# Force https with www from htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanted to redirected all non www and non https urls to https with www from htaccess.

I tried many codes by googling but could not get solved my problems

I am sharing my existing htaccess code

```
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2000M
php_value memory_limit 100000M
php_value max_execution_time 1000000

#### Rule for Error Page - 404 ####
ErrorDocument 404 http://gpe360.com/index_home.php

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<Files index.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip

Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^villas/rent.php$ rent.php?$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^house/homes.php$ homes.php?$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^apartment/apartment.php$ apartment.php?$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^apartmentland/land.php$ land.php?$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ property_details.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^region--(.*)--(.*)\.html$ region_details.php?rid=$1 
RewriteRule ^cyprus_details\.html$ cyprus_details.php
RewriteRule ^agent-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ view_public_profile.php?uid=$1
RewriteRule ^News-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ news_detail.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^Resource-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ useful_resource_details.php?rid=$1
RewriteRule ^independent_account.php(.*) /makepayment/account.php?ac_type=2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^professional_account.php(.*) /makepayment/account.php?ac_type=3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gpe360\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gpe360.com/$1 [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.gpe360.com
#Options -Idexes
```

The live url is www.gpe360.com.

Comment: And would you care to tell us _why_ all those millions of solutions you tried did not work for you? I mean they _do_ work, so why not for you? What is your actual issue? What does "do not work" actually mean? This reads as if you have no idea how to do things and just dump something here , then expect others to tell you how to do your work.

Comment: The error was "To many redirections".

Comment: That is a pretty precise error. Though it only makes sense along with the exact code you tried when receiving that error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule just after `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteCond {HTTPS} on
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

remove your previous attempt for testing in your code.

Comment: It does not redirect the css and js files

Comment: try to use this in your html page `<base href="http://www.example.com/" />`. replace example with your host name.